# Another people!

Tags: determiners

A little while ago, I was listening to the radio show "*A way with words*" (episode: Upstairs basement 9 June 2014) when I heard the host Grant  saying that phrase. I had to do a little research and confirmed that "another" can only be used with singular nouns and not with plural nouns. People is a plural noun.

If you conduct a COCA search, you'll get 74 hits as of this writing from different register sources. I know that people can have the meaning of "*all the men, women and children who live in a particular country*" as in "*The French are known as a food-loving people.*". Because of time constraints I cannot go any further, and curiosity makes me want to know now and not later whether this usage is informal. Is it so?

**[Another as a determiner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another)** (From Cambridge's website)

We use another with singular nouns:

> - *Would you like **another** cup of coffee?*
> - *You’ve met Linda, but I have **another** sister who you haven’t met, called Margaret.*
> - *I don’t like this place. Is there **another** café around here we could go to?* (alternative or different)

**Another: typical errors**
- Another is singular. We don’t use it with plural nouns:

> ***Other*** interesting places to visit include the old harbour and the castle.

Not: <strike>Another interesting places to visit</strike>...

Comment: When *people* is used like *society,* **as in your own example regarding the French**, it is a singular noun. And the usage is not "informal."

Comment: Another synonym for people here is *population*.  Just like society, this word refers to a single group made of many parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38512/another-people/38531#comment71627_38512) points out, *a people* is possible with the specific meaning ["The members of a particular nation, community, or ethnic group"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/people) (Oxford Dictionaries), and so of course *another people* is possible when this is what's intended.

In [this particular *A Way With Words* podcast](https://soundcloud.com/waywordradio/upstairs-basement-full-episode), however, *people* isn't being used that way.  In this case your problem stems from mishearing *and other* as *another*.  The speaker didn't pronounce the /d/ in *and*, so it ended up sounding the same as if he'd said *another*.  We're left to context to figure out which was actually spoken, and as you observed yourself, using *another people* this way would be quite strange, so we can tell it must be *and other*.

Why plural, then, and not *and another person said*?  Because the speaker was giving representative samples of the discussion and (apparently) multiple people said things like the quotes he gave.

Comment: To be honest, I was listening to the show "in the background" while I was browsing a book! It's not an excuse though because my listening skills are not on par with native speakers yet. I never thought of the case where it might be "and other"! Thank you very much @snailboat